# openni.launch is neither a launch file in package [openni_launch] nor is [openni_launch] a launch file name

Tags: opencv, gpu, ros, launch

I would like to run my code in the GPU.

I have two OpenCV versions are:

1. ros-kinetic-opencv3 includes `cv_bridge`.............................................just with CPU
2. OpenCV with GPU enhancements needs to build `cv_bridge` .......... just with GPU

when running the code, the system considers  ros-kinetic-opencv3 `default`. So, I removed ros-kinetic-opencv3 by: `sudo apt remove ros-kinetic-opencv3` then,
I built cv_bridge for OpenCV with GPU enhancements like [this](https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv) ( I downloaded vision_opencv in my catkin_ws/src, then used `catkin_make` and `source ./devel/setup.bash`)

I tried to run two cameras:

**1) name of the camera: ASUS xtion**
when I run the camera: `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch`, get this ERROR

`[openni.launch] is neither a launch file in package [openni_launch] nor is [openni_launch] a launch file name The traceback for the exception was written to the log file`.

when using this command: `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-openni-launch` , it is work but run with CPU not GPU why? because of it installed `ros-kinetic-opencv3` and I need to use the first step (remove ros-kinetic-opencv3), this means a closed cycle

**2) name of the camera: Orbbec Astra**

I did the first and second steps like ASUS xtion.
when I run the camera: `roslaunch astra_camera astra.launch` get this error:

```py
    WARNING: Package name "cvTest" does not follow the naming conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only contain lower case letters, digits, underscores, and dashes.
    ... logging to /home/redhwan/.ros/log/aa3b63a6-eeea-11e9-880f-1c1b0d1de755/roslaunch-redhwan-8176.log
    Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
    Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
    Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 306, in main
        p.start()
      File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 268, in start
        self._start_infrastructure()
      File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 217, in _start_infrastructure
        self._load_config()
      File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 132, in _load_config
        roslaunch_strs=self.roslaunch_strs, verbose=self.verbose)
      File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/config.py", line 451, in load_config_default
        loader.load(f, config, verbose=verbose)
      File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 749, in load
        self._load_launch(launch, ros_config, is_core=core, filename=filename, argv=argv, verbose=verbose)
      File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 721, in _load_launch
        self._recurse_load(ros_config, launch.childNodes, self.root_context, None, is_core, verbose)
      File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 655, in _recurse_load
        default_machine, is_core, verbose)
      File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 685, in _recurse_load
        val = self._include_tag(tag, context, ros_config, default_machine, is_core, verbose)
      File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 95, in call
        return f(*args, **kwds)
      File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 589, in _include_tag
        inc_filename = self.resolve_args(tag.attributes['file'].value, context)
      File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 183, in resolve_args
        return substitution_args.resolve_args(args, context=context.resolve_dict, resolve_anon=self.resolve_anon)
      File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 370, in resolve_args
        resolved = _resolve_args(resolved, context, resolve_anon, commands)
      File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 383, in _resolve_args
        resolved = commands[command](resolved, a, args, context)
      File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 151, in _find
        source_path_to_packages=source_path_to_packages)
      File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 197, in _find_executable
        full_path = _get_executable_path(rp.get_path(args[0]), path)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 203, in get_path
        raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
    ResourceNotFound: rgbd_launch
    ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
    ROS path [1]=/home/redhwan/catkin_ws/src
    ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share
```

I fixed this error using : `sudo apt install ros-kinetic-rgbd-launch` it is work but run with CPU not GPU why? because of it installed `ros-kinetic-opencv3` and I need to use the first step (remove ros-kinetic-opencv3), this means a closed cycle

please help me or any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like running

```
sudo apt install ros-kinetic-rgbd-launch
```

helps at least

Answer (score 0):

**Source ROS Environment:**
After installing or making changes, make sure to source your ROS environment by running:

```
source /your_path/setup.bash
```